# Min-height 100% for TABLE divs

Tags: html, css, css-tables, doctype

I'm trying to make my div min-height 100% of screen. I understand, that there are many questions about it, but I have condition: my div should be display:table. So there is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: table; background-color: red; width: 100%; min-height: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">123</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works in Chrome and IE. Div is really 100% height. But it doesn't work in FF, Opera and Safari. Is there any solution for divs with table display? May be changing doctype can help me? I tried variants, but they are not also cross-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace:

```
min-height:100%;
```

with

```
height:100%;
```

works perfectly for chrome and FF here.

Comment: It really works, but I need min-height.. Content of div can have more height than 100% of window..

Comment: Hmmm... So, because of default overflow:visible, everything will be ok?

Comment: Yes, it is right :) Thank you very much! Two minutes to accept

Comment: Looks like Firefox is incorrectly giving elements set to `display: table` an inline style rather than a block style.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt `table-block` isn't a valid `display` value: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but `123` isn't really valid content for an element whose `display` property is set to `table`. This is on par with having the following markup:

```
<table>123</table>
```

Your table has no rows or cells, yet you're expecting the content to be displayed somewhere.

With the CSS `table` display value you should at least have a child element set to display as `table-cell`:

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        123
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you say about being on a par with `<table>123</table>` is incorrect. `<table>123</table>` will be parsed into `123` followed by a empty table. `<div style='display:table'>123</div>` will cause `123` to be inside an anonymous table-cell object, inside an anonymous table-row object inside the 'table' div. So an full table layout is generated in just the same way as the anonymous table-row object is generated in your "corrected" example.